# Bumblebee not working anymore after installing the new nvdia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I had managed to make bumblebee work yesterday and today i launch update manager and i see some new nvidia drivers. I dont know why but i installed them...

I shouldnt have done that lol

Now im back with this classic error

```
[   84.300183] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[   84.300310] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Of course I've googled it before, there are so many threads about this problem but I couldnt find a solution.

Ive blacklisted nouveau, i tried to blacklist nvidia

In the conf, driver=nvidia and kerneldrive=nvidia too

i dont know what to do anymore

i am thinking about removing linux and going back to 7, its so hard its so exhausting please help

Comment: Please search before posting a question,also the editor keeps giving suggestion. If you tried the answer & failed, mention that too. Here are few relevant questions - [First try](http://askubuntu.com/q/202644/35775), [sencond try](http://askubuntu.com/q/215146/35775) & [third try](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178069/bumblebeecannot-access-secondary-gpu-error-could-not-load-gpu-driver). Please remember, you modified `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`. Please check the answer of 2nd link, I posted

Comment: I already did all that and i wrote in my post that i had done it. Linux headers are not a problem. I think its relative to the new nvidia driver that I installed this morning and i suspect alot of people are gonna have the same problem than me...

Comment: maybe because of the primus update in bumblee 3.1? I will search a bit tommorow. i am not having any problem as of now. Please mention the graphics card model also,. By mentioning , I meant to say which answer you have tried already in my earlier comment.. btw Your first comment did came to my notification

Comment: I have an Intel HD400 and geforce 650.

Comment: anyway i give up, my laptop is too much of a hassle to make it work with linux

Answer (score 0):

I think that I was in this situation in the past and that this helped.

In the terminal type or copy paste:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-current
```

Then to make the optimus card functional you can try to install bumblebee again
[here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee).